# MSChart Show Only Inserted Dates, no blanks

Tags: .net, vb.net, mschart

I've been searching how to fix this behavior with MS Chart for a few days now and unfortunately everything I've found so far is not helping.

I have a Horizontal Bar Chart that I'm loading with sales data in a specific time frame. This data is already "Massaged" into how I want it using a Date Dimension table so that I can shove zeroes where no data exists.

This means my data always has exactly the required amount of points requested at all times regardless of it being Daily, Weekly, Monthly or Yearly. You ask for 7 days you get 7 rows, you ask for 12 weeks you get 12 rows you ask for 3 months you get 3 rows. Always (Yearly may be a beginning of time situation at the moment so we won't talk about that one.)

[image: Working as Intended]

Now Daily works fine but the moment I switch to the other modes the chart completely ignores the fact I'm giving it a very specific number of points and instead puts in every date in the calendar in between my data points.

[image: Not Working as Intended]
As I said I've tried various solutions I could find but they either make things worse or cause errors.

- At first I was databinding the chart but then switched to manually inserting the points
- I've set IsXValueIndexed to true and that just caused the chart to show no values at all...
  [image: WTF]
- Adding AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel causes errors about needing to all be non-empty and unique
- IntervalOffset values seem to do nothing

```
    Private Sub LoadChart()

        Dim oDT As New DataTable
        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand

        Dim sSQLDateCTE As String = "WITH Date_CTE as ( " & _
                "SELECT [Date] as SaleDate " & _
                "FROM [DateDimension] "
        Dim sWHEREDateCTE As String = "WHERE [Date] BETWEEN DATEADD({0},-{1},GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() "
        Dim sSQLSUM As String = "), SUM_CTE as ( " & _
                "SELECT F01 as UPCCode, F254 as SaleDate, SUM(F64) as UnitsSold " & _
                "FROM {0} " & _
                "WHERE F1034 = 3 AND F64 <> 0 AND F01 = @UPCCode " & _
                "AND F254 IN (SELECT saledate FROM Date_CTE) " & _
                "GROUP BY F01,F254) " & _
                "Select DC.SaleDate ,ISNULL(SC.UnitsSold,0) as UnitsSold " & _
                "FROM Date_CTE as DC " & _
                "LEFT OUTER JOIN SUM_CTE as SC " & _
                "ON SC.SaleDate = DC.SaleDate " & _
                "ORDER BY DC.SaleDate ASC "

        Dim sSQL As String = ""

        Try

            Dim PeriodRow As DataRow = oAppEnv.dtPeriods.Select(String.Format("DPPeriodID = {0}", cboPeriods.SelectedValue)).FirstOrDefault

            Dim DurationRow As DataRow = oAppEnv.dtDurations.Select(String.Format("DDDurationID = '{0}'", cboDuration.SelectedValue)).FirstOrDefault

            Select Case PeriodRow.Item("DPPeriodAbbrev")
                Case "D"
                    sWHEREDateCTE = String.Format(sWHEREDateCTE, "DD", DurationRow.Item("DDDurationLength"))
                    sSQLSUM = String.Format(sSQLSUM, "RPT_ITM_D")
                    sSQL = sSQLDateCTE & sWHEREDateCTE & sSQLSUM
                Case "W"
                    sWHEREDateCTE = String.Format(sWHEREDateCTE, "WW", DurationRow.Item("DDDurationLength")) & " AND Weekday = 1 "
                    sSQLSUM = String.Format(sSQLSUM, "RPT_ITM_W")
                    sSQL = sSQLDateCTE & sWHEREDateCTE & sSQLSUM
                Case "M"
                    sWHEREDateCTE = String.Format(sWHEREDateCTE, "MM", DurationRow.Item("DDDurationLength")) & " AND [DAY] = DATEPART(Day,getdate()) "
                    sSQLSUM = String.Format(sSQLSUM, "RPT_ITM_M")
                    sSQL = sSQLDateCTE & sWHEREDateCTE & sSQLSUM
                Case "Y"
                    '????

            End Select

            sqlCmd.CommandText = sSQL

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UPCCode", sUPCCode)

            oDT = oAppEnv.oLogiDM.GetSQLData(sqlCmd)

            ctSalesData.ChartAreas.Clear()
            ctSalesData.ChartAreas.Add("Sales")
            ctSalesData.Series.Clear()
            ctSalesData.Series.Add("Sales")
            ctSalesData.Series("Sales").ChartType = Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar
            'ctSalesData.Series(0).IsXValueIndexed = True
            'ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Days
            'ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalOffset = -1

            If oDT IsNot Nothing Then

                '//Get the Date range.

                Dim oSortDV As DataView = oDT.DefaultView
                oSortDV.Sort = "UnitsSold DESC"

                'ctSalesData.DataSource = oDT

                For Each row In oDT.Rows
                    ctSalesData.Series(0).Points.AddXY(row.item("SaleDate"), row.item("UnitsSold"))
                Next
                'ctSalesData.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel()

                ctSalesData.Series(0).CustomProperties = "PixelPointWidth = 15"
                ctSalesData.Series(0).IsValueShownAsLabel = True


                Dim MinDate As Date = oDT.Rows(0).Item("SaleDate")
                Dim Maxdate As Date = oDT.Rows(oDT.Rows.Count - 1).Item("SaleDate")

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = MinDate.ToOADate
                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = Maxdate.ToOADate

                If oDT.Rows.Count > 14 Then
                    Dim ZoomDate As Date = oDT.Rows(14).Item("SaleDate")
                    ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(MinDate.ToOADate, ZoomDate.ToOADate)
                End If

                ctSalesData.Series(0).XValueType = Charting.ChartValueType.Date

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = 0

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = Math.Ceiling(oSortDV(0).Item("UnitsSold") / 10) * 10

                If ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = oSortDV(0).Item("UnitsSold") Then
                    ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum += 10
                End If

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).CursorX.AutoScroll = True

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Number
                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = Charting.ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 20
                'ctSalesData.Series(0).XValueMember = "SaleDate"
                'ctSalesData.Series(0).YValueMembers = "UnitsSold"
                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = False


            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

- Also tried changing the points to be a generic counter

```
        Dim iCnt As Integer = 0
        For Each row In oDT.Rows
             ctSalesData.Series(0).Points.AddXY(iCnt, row.item("UnitsSold"))
             ctSalesData.Series(0).Points(iCnt).AxisLabel = row.item("SaleDate")
             iCnt += 1
        Next
```

But I think that just broke my zoom code since it's all date based.

So; How the hell do I get rid of these blank wastes of space and show only the data points that I insert?

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone who is/was/will experience the same issue, so far the only way I've been able to get around this annoyance is to do the Generic Counter thing I mentioned previously but rework my zoom code.

[image: Working now]

Here's the reworked code for anyone interested.

```
    Private Sub LoadChart()

        Dim oDT As New DataTable
        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand

        Dim sSQLDateCTE As String = "WITH Date_CTE as ( " & _
                "SELECT [Date] as SaleDate " & _
                "FROM [DateDimension] "
        Dim sWHEREDateCTE As String = "WHERE [Date] BETWEEN DATEADD({0},-{1},GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() "
        Dim sSQLSUM As String = "), SUM_CTE as ( " & _
                "SELECT F01 as UPCCode, F254 as SaleDate, SUM(F64) as UnitsSold " & _
                "FROM {0} " & _
                "WHERE F1034 = 3 AND F64 <> 0 AND F01 = @UPCCode " & _
                "AND F254 IN (SELECT saledate FROM Date_CTE) " & _
                "GROUP BY F01,F254) " & _
                "Select DC.SaleDate ,ISNULL(SC.UnitsSold,0) as UnitsSold " & _
                "FROM Date_CTE as DC " & _
                "LEFT OUTER JOIN SUM_CTE as SC " & _
                "ON SC.SaleDate = DC.SaleDate " & _
                "ORDER BY DC.SaleDate ASC "

        Dim sSQL As String = ""

        Try

            Dim PeriodRow As DataRow = oAppEnv.dtPeriods.Select(String.Format("DPPeriodID = {0}", cboPeriods.SelectedValue)).FirstOrDefault

            Dim DurationRow As DataRow = oAppEnv.dtDurations.Select(String.Format("DDDurationID = '{0}'", cboDuration.SelectedValue)).FirstOrDefault

            Select Case PeriodRow.Item("DPPeriodAbbrev")
                Case "D"
                    sWHEREDateCTE = String.Format(sWHEREDateCTE, "DD", DurationRow.Item("DDDurationLength"))
                    sSQLSUM = String.Format(sSQLSUM, "RPT_ITM_D")
                    sSQL = sSQLDateCTE & sWHEREDateCTE & sSQLSUM
                Case "W"
                    sWHEREDateCTE = String.Format(sWHEREDateCTE, "WW", DurationRow.Item("DDDurationLength")) & " AND Weekday = 1 "
                    sSQLSUM = String.Format(sSQLSUM, "RPT_ITM_W")
                    sSQL = sSQLDateCTE & sWHEREDateCTE & sSQLSUM
                Case "M"
                    sWHEREDateCTE = String.Format(sWHEREDateCTE, "MM", DurationRow.Item("DDDurationLength")) & " AND [DAY] = DATEPART(Day,getdate()) "
                    sSQLSUM = String.Format(sSQLSUM, "RPT_ITM_M")
                    sSQL = sSQLDateCTE & sWHEREDateCTE & sSQLSUM
                Case "Y"
                    '????

            End Select

            sqlCmd.CommandText = sSQL

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UPCCode", sUPCCode)

            oDT = oAppEnv.oLogiDM.GetSQLData(sqlCmd)

            ctSalesData.ChartAreas.Clear()
            ctSalesData.ChartAreas.Add("Sales")
            ctSalesData.Series.Clear()
            ctSalesData.Series.Add("Sales")
            ctSalesData.Series("Sales").ChartType = Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar
            ctSalesData.Series(0).IsXValueIndexed = True
            'ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Days
            'ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalOffset = -1

            If oDT IsNot Nothing Then

                '//Get the highest sold item so we can set the Y axis to bigger than the biggest

                Dim oSortDV As DataView = oDT.DefaultView
                oSortDV.Sort = "UnitsSold DESC"

                'ctSalesData.DataSource = oDT
                Dim iCnt As Integer = 0
                For Each row In oDT.Rows
                    ctSalesData.Series(0).Points.AddXY(iCnt, row.item("UnitsSold"))
                    ctSalesData.Series(0).Points(iCnt).AxisLabel = row.item("SaleDate")
                    iCnt += 1
                Next
                'ctSalesData.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel()

                ctSalesData.Series(0).CustomProperties = "PixelPointWidth = 15"
                ctSalesData.Series(0).IsValueShownAsLabel = True


                'Dim MinDate As Date = oDT.Rows(0).Item("SaleDate")
                'Dim Maxdate As Date = oDT.Rows(oDT.Rows.Count - 1).Item("SaleDate")

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 0
                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = oDT.Rows.Count + 1

                If oDT.Rows.Count > 21 Then
                    Dim ZoomDate As Date = oDT.Rows(14).Item("SaleDate")
                    ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, 22)
                End If

                'ctSalesData.Series(0).XValueType = Charting.ChartValueType.Date

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = 0

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = Math.Ceiling(oSortDV(0).Item("UnitsSold") / 10) * 10

                If ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = oSortDV(0).Item("UnitsSold") Then
                    ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum += 10
                End If

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).CursorX.AutoScroll = True

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Number
                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = Charting.ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll

                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 21
                ''ctSalesData.Series(0).XValueMember = "SaleDate"
                ''ctSalesData.Series(0).YValueMembers = "UnitsSold"
                ctSalesData.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = False


            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Still would be nice to get the Date method to behave properly though as this is an annoying workaround.